# internalFormat in glCompressedTexImage2D specifies format in texture or the format in OpenGL(GPU)?

Tags: opengl, textures

This is a little silly question but the link (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCompressedTexImage2D.xml) says it "Specifies the format of the compressed image data stored at address data." which means the actual compressed texture image format. That is what I thought.

Then why is it called "internal format"? Shouldnt it just be called Format?

Because Internal Format in glTexImage2D() means the format in which the image data is stored in GPU internally.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of compressed textures is, that the image data the GPU holds in and accesses from its memory is compressed to save space and – even more important – memory bandwidth. So it makes sense that the internal format defines which compression to use, if any.

So what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is, if the image is compressed in the GPU or is a compressed image read from the application?

Comment: May be I didnt have a good understanding of glCompressedTexImage2D. From what I understand now is that glCompressedTexImage2D  reads an image and stores in the GPU in compressed format?  All this while, I thought glCompressedTexImage2D  was used to read a compressed image into GPU.

Comment: @kvikram: When you use `glCompressedTexImage2D (...)` it is because you are passing image data that was ***already*** compressed to GL. It stays in this compressed format. When you use a compressed internal format with `glTexImage2D (...)`, GL compresses the image data during pixel transfer. In both cases, the texture is stored in a compressed format, the only difference is what format it started out in.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman. Thanks, now I understand what this API is for!

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, maybe you can update your question with the information you provided in your comment. It seems to be the relevant one for the question.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: Pardon? This is not my question... did you mean to say that I should write that as an answer?